# How do I match a Class<?> against a specific Class instance in a Hamcrest Matcher?

Tags: java, generics, junit, junit4, hamcrest

I would like to be able to assert that the annotation value matches the expected class:

```
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;

public final class AnnotatedClassTest {
    @Test
    public void someAnnotationIsString() {
        assertThat(
            AnnotatedClass.class.getAnnotation(SomeAnnotation.class).value(),
            is(equalTo(String.class));
    }
}
```

However, this is a type error:

```
AnnotatedClassTest.java:9: error: no suitable method found for assertThat(Class<CAP#1>,Matcher<Class<String>>)
        assertThat(
        ^
    method MatcherAssert.<T#1>assertThat(T#1,Matcher<? super T#1>) is not applicable
      (actual argument Matcher<Class<String>> cannot be converted to Matcher<? super Class<CAP#1>> by method invocation conversion)
    method MatcherAssert.<T#2>assertThat(String,T#2,Matcher<? super T#2>) is not applicable
      (cannot instantiate from arguments because actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method MatcherAssert.assertThat(String,boolean) is not applicable
      (actual argument Class<CAP#1> cannot be converted to String by method invocation conversion)
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Object declared in method <T#1>assertThat(T#1,Matcher<? super T#1>)
    T#2 extends Object declared in method <T#2>assertThat(String,T#2,Matcher<? super T#2>)
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?
1 error
```

Here is the annotation class:

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface SomeAnnotation {
    Class<?> value();
}
```

And the class to which I apply that annotation:

```
@SomeAnnotation(String.class)
public final class AnnotatedClass {
}
```

The type error occurs because:

```
Class<?> value = AnnotatedClass.class.getAnnotation(SomeAnnotation.class).value();
```

And:

```
Matcher<Class<String>> classMatcher = is(equalTo(String.class));
```

Can't satisfy the signature I intend to target which is:

```
<T> void assertThat(T, Matcher<? super T>)
```

Which made more specific by fixing **T** based on the first parameter would be:

```
void assertThat(Class<?>, Matcher<? super Class<?>>)
```

I like the uniformity of **assertThat** and would prefer to avoid **assertEquals**.

Here is how to do it with **assertEquals** (notably does not answer my question):

```
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public final class AnnotatedClassTest {
    @Test
    public void someAnnotationIsString() {
        assertEquals(
            String.class,
            AnnotatedClass.class.getAnnotation(SomeAnnotation.class).value());
    }
}
```

### How do I match a `Class<?>` against a specific Class instance in a Hamcrest Matcher?

Stating that this is impossible is an acceptable answer if you can provide a compelling explanation.

Comment: Very well-written question.

Comment: It's worth it when I get great answers as I have here.  Usually handy for future travellers as well :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A rather ugly way to do it is to use raw types.

```
// this declaration is RAW
Class expected = String.class;
assertThat(AnnotatedClass.class.getAnnotation(SomeAnnotation.class)
                .value(), is(equalTo(expected)));
```

But a **nicer** way to do it is to specify a generic type argument for the invocation of `equalTo(..)`.

```
Class<?> expected = String.class;
assertThat(AnnotatedClass.class.getAnnotation(SomeAnnotation.class)
        .value(), is(CoreMatchers.<Class<?>>equalTo(expected)));
```

(You don't need to extract `String.class` into a variable.)

Comment: assertThat(AnnotatedClass.class.getAnnotation(SomeAnnotation.class).value(), is(equalTo((Class) String.class))); also works well.  Thank you :)

Comment: I knew there was an escape hatch, but I forgot raw types.  I like the type witness solution as well.  For tests I'd use the raw for brevity, but production I'd use the witness for better safety.